# Simple Adjacency matric creation with Pytorch Tensors

Tags: pytorch, adjacency-matrix

I was trying to write a simple function to create a random adjacency matrix in the following way :

```
def create_adj(a):
    a[a>0.5] = 1
    a[a<=0.5] = 0
    return a
```

given that `a` is assumed to be a `torch.Tensor()` as input, but I get the following error:

```
TypeError: 'int' object does not support item assignment
```

If I do things separately (i.e. not inside a function), I simply do:

```
>> a = torch.rand(3,3)
>> a[a>0.5] = 1
>> a[a<=0.5] = 0

>> a
 tensor([[1., 1., 1.],
         [0., 0., 0.],
         [1., 0., 0.]])
```

But I don't understand what I'm doing wrong in the function.

Comment: What shape does `a` have? Could you provide a minimal example?

Comment: Sure, I've added wextra info in the question.

Comment: And `create_adj(torch.rand(3,3))` raises an error?

Comment: But if you do like that how can you recall it in the function and modifying it? create_adj(a=torch.rand(3,3)) but still the same error

Comment: That was just an example, just do `a = torch.rand(3,3); create_adj(a)` and you will see the difference.

Answer (score 1):

I would assume you are not passing the correct variable your `create_adj` function. As long as `a` is a `torch.tensor`, then it should work.

Alternatively, you can directly use the mask as result:

```
def create_adj(x): 
  return (a > .5).float()
```